# Who dictates the sizeof basic types in c++, is it the OS or the Compiler?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, 64-bit

Before someone says that this is a duplicate, I read most of questions about this topic, but they don't seem to answer this question.

I know that size of basic types in c++ is implementation-defined, so the compiler in **theory** is free to choose any size as long as it fit the standard specification about this basic types :

```
sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)

sizeof(short)     * CHAR_BIT >= 16
sizeof(int)       * CHAR_BIT >= 16
sizeof(long)      * CHAR_BIT >= 32
```

What I don't understand is when someone says that windows choose `LLP64` Data Model for 64-machines, and Unix choose `LP64` (`ILP64` for early versioins) for 64-machines.

Does this mean that every native compiler working on windows/unix should stick with this data model ? if the answer is yes, what is the reason for this restriction, does it have something to do with the `OS` API, ABI or something ?

**Update:**

Now that I know the answer to my questions, I will try to explain the answer here so that anyone who had the same questions as I did can find an answer.

**Who decides the sizeof basic types in C++, is it the OS or the Compiler ?**

Sizes of basic data types in c++ are implementation-defined, which mean it's up to the compiler author to decide the sizes of this data types as long as they don't violate c++ standard specification about minimum ranges that each data type must cover.

**What does it mean that windows choose `LLP64` data model? Does this mean that  I can't have a compiler with different data model for windows-64 ?**

> Note that a programming model is a choice made on a per-compiler
>   basis, and several can coexist on the same OS. However, the
>   programming model chosen as the primary model for the OS API typically
>   dominates.

[Wikipedia: 64-bit data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models)

So you can have a compiler with a different data model than `LLP64` on windows-64, but this will limit you from using The windows OS API, since the implementation of this API is compiled using a compiler with `LLP64` Data model, and you can't link object files that got compiled using compilers with different data models.

Comment: De-Jure this is unspecified. The only restriction is from the standard specification and is the one you wrote. De-Facto it depends of the architecture of the hardware being targeted.

Comment: It is of course up to the guy that wrote the compiler.  You are free to ignore the common choices on an operating system.  Don't expect a lot of users to be thrilled about it, Darwin sorts this out.

Comment: @HansPassant what are the consequences of ignoring windows-64bit Data Model LLP64, and choosing a compiler that uses LP64 ?

Comment: The consequence is a bunch of pissed-off users that didn't use the typedefs like they should and thus have a hard time porting their program.  They wrote `long` instead of `LONG` because everybody knows that long has been 32-bits *forever* and uppercase type names suck.

Comment: Does this mean that if I choose a compiler that uses a different Data Model of what windows-64bit I'll have hard time using windows Dynamic-Shared Library and API ?

Comment: Roughly, yes.  You cannot use the Windows SDK as-is.  There are alternatives, like MinGW-w64.  Troubled project btw, seems that the mingw-w64 guys don't get along with the mingw guys at all.  Common problem if you try to talk using different language rules.

Comment: If Im compiling a program for windows I'll probably use some windows API that have the implementation compiled using a compiler that chooses LLP64, so when I try to link both object files(My object files and Windows API object files) I guess there will be an issue since one assume that long is 4 bytes and the other assume it is 8 bytes, is this correct ?

Comment: Your title and post ask different questions.

Comment: @NeilKirk My tilte question is whether Data Model changes from one compiler to another independently from the `OS`, or that different compilers have to choose the same Data Model on an `OS`. 
My question in my Post is in simple words, what is the meaning of windows chooses a specific Data Model, does it mean that the windows API implementation are compiled are compiled with a compiler that uses that specific Data Model, in this case does this mean that multiple data model compilers can coexist on the same OS, but dominant one is the data model used for the OS API

Comment: @AlexDan Last I checked, Windows API assumes int and long are 32-bit, and will break otherwise. So although a new compiler could come along on Windows with 64-bit ints, it wouldn't be compatible with Windows API so kind of pointless.

Comment: I think this makes sense. So it's the platform that suggest the sizeof basic types, the compiler doesn't have to follow this suggestions but in practice it does. The platform in this context may mean the operating system where the compiler get influenced by the `OS API`, and also the platform in the context of hardware or CPU architecture in embedded systems where application will run on top of the hardware directly so the compiler will usually (but it doesn't have to) follow the architecture suggestions.

Comment: The hardware usually leads the author(s) of the compiler to make intelligent decisions.  And no, assume there is no OS, because the OS itself is just software that needed to be compiled so that it would run on the specified hardware..  First the hardware is built.  Then the compilers are built for the hardware, then the software gets written..

Comment: If you answered your own question (or the commenters led you to an answer), consider posting it as an answer and accepting it, so that this question does not appear in my unanswered questions tab (and so people can vote your answer up).